# My dogs EXTREME seperation anxiety. When do i give him the treat?

Tags: dogs, training

if he isn't barking he is trying to escape. how do i positively reinforce my dog when he never stops the bad behavior? I never know when to give him a treat because he NEVER stops the bad behavior. Ill wait for hours at a time trying to be patient but he doesnt stop. He has severe separation anxiety and has developed a self distructive trait. Now he will jam his face into the floor during his freak outs and when I come home he has cuts on his face. HOW DO I GET HIM TO STOP?!?!?! HES HURTING

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Severe separation anxiety in dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/193/severe-separation-anxiety-in-dog)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is quite obviously too severe to solve with treats. That's like trying to treat a person with schizophrenia or clinical depression with sugar cubes.

Severe separation anxiety must be treated with care and as the mental illness it is. Your dog shouldn't be left alone for hours *because* he'll freak out and never stop his destructive behavior. If you want to treat his anxiety yourself, you need to avoid any freak-outs at all. That's the only way your dog can learn that being alone  is manageable doesn't mean being abandoned.

The best advice I can give you is to hire a professional dog trainer specialized in problematic behavior. They should ideally come to your home, observe how you and your dog act and interact with each other and give you hints to change your behavior.