# My dog won't house train and has difficulty being left alone

Tags: dogs, training

I recently got a dog with separation anxiety. He won't go in his crate or go to the bathroom outside. How can I house and crate-train him?

Comment: Please use the search function. There are a lot of questions about crate training. Also problems with going outside are asked repeatedly. If you do not find ideas for solutions or the solutions do not work for you, come back to your question and add the information how your case differs. Your question as it is is to broad and has not enough information about the problem.

Comment: General recommendation: Do a dog training class with your pup. This will train *you* in how to train your dog, and give you a chance to get expert advice on how to deal with specific issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Severe separation anxiety in dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/193/severe-separation-anxiety-in-dog)

Comment: Honestly, this doesn't sound like a problem you can fix via the internet. I suggest finding a dog trainer (not a puppy class) in your local area who visits you at home, analyzes your own and your dog's behavior and gives you advice on what to change.